# Connect Arduino to nodejs server using websocket

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, arduino

First, I have :
- An autonomous arduino (battery + wifi shield)
- A nodejs server + socket.io module

I want to connect my Arduino to the nodejs server and add real time possibilities.
I don't know if is possible to use websocket on arduino's side (client side) like in a browser like chrome to allow the server side to call a method on client side with something like :

```
socket.on(myMethod,...)
```

I saw libraries like noduino of jhonny-five but always using serial port (with usb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Socket.IO Arduino Client, yes you can. https://github.com/billroy/socket.io-arduino-client

Comment: oh seems to be fine, but the example are not compiling and explainations are not correct (Example used seems to not be present in package).

Comment: I too get build errors, saying that "error: bitlash.h: No such file or directory" ... when I try all examples.